# HTML Email Signature not displaying correctly on Dark Mode in Mail iOS, Mac

Tags: iphone, macos, email, html-email, ios-darkmode

My email signature works perfectly fine on iOS Mail in the default Light Mode.

However if you switch to Dark Mode and send an email with it, the background of the full message becomes white. The content is also touching the edge on the left hand side, which doesn't look good.

Ideally I would like the background in Dark Mode to be transparent, dark text to switch to white etc.
I have tried various things such as setting all the fonts/ backgrounds to #000000, however that didn't change anything.

Please see my code below, together with a screenshot taken in Dark Mode:

```
<table width="320" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 320px; max-width: 320px; background-color: transparent;">
<tr>
    <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 19px; color: #000000;">
                                Joe Bloggs
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; color: #3d3c3f;">
                                Project Manager
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="320" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> 
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="line-height: 18px; border-spacing: 0;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="center" valign="middle">
                                                <img alt="Mobile" border="0" width="12" height="12" style="border: 0; height: 12px; width: 12px;" src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/phone.png" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                                <a href="tel:+4407777777777" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #888888; color: #888888 !important; text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none;">
                                                    &nbsp;+44 (0)7777 777777
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="center" valign="middle">
                                                <img alt="Email" border="0" width="12" height="12" style="border: 0; height: 12px; width: 12px;" src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/email.png" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                                <a href="mailto:test@gmail.com" title="Email me" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0b9cab; color: #0b9cab !important; text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none;">
                                                    &nbsp;test@gmail.com
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="center" valign="middle">
                                                <img alt="Website" border="0" width="12" height="12" style="border: 0; height: 12px; width: 12px;" src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/www.png" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                                <a
                                                    href="#"
                                                    title="Visit our website"
                                                    target="_blank"
                                                    style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #0b9cab; text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none;"
                                                >
                                                    &nbsp;website-address.co.uk
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="center" valign="middle">
                                                <img alt="Address" border="0" width="12" height="12" style="border: 0; height: 12px; width: 12px;" src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/address.png" />
                                            </td>

                                            <td style="padding-right: 3px; font-size: 13px;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #888888; color: #888888 !important; padding-left: 2px; text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none;">
                                                    19 London Road, London,
                                                </span>
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-size: 13px;" align="left" valign="middle"></td>

                                            <td style="font-size: 13px; padding-left: 3px;" align="left" valign="middle">
                                                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #888888; color: #888888 !important; text-decoration: none !important; text-decoration: none;">
                                                    LE43 0RR, United Kingdom
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="320" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="320" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 2px; background-color: #0b9cab;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="320" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 10px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <table width="320" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="320px" style="background-color: #000000; border-spacing: 0;">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" width="90" style="width: 90px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff; padding-left: 10px;">
                    Follow us:
                </td>
                <td height="32" valign="middle" style="height: 32px;">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img
                                        alt="Facebook icon"
                                        title="Instagram"
                                        border="0"
                                        width="16"
                                        height="16"
                                        style="display: block; border: 0; height: 16px; width: 16px;"
                                        src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/fb-2ef13da0.png"
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img
                                        alt="Instagram icon"
                                        title="Instagram"
                                        border="0"
                                        width="16"
                                        height="16"
                                        style="display: block; border: 0; height: 16px; width: 16px;"
                                        src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/insta-3478a59b.png"
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img
                                        alt="Pinterest icon"
                                        title="Pinterest"
                                        border="0"
                                        width="16"
                                        height="16"
                                        style="display: block; border: 0; height: 16px; width: 16px;"
                                        src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/pin.png"
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="middle" style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <img
                                        alt="Website icon"
                                        title="Visit our website"
                                        border="0"
                                        width="14"
                                        height="14"
                                        style="display: block;border: 0; height: 16px; width: 16px;"
                                        src="https://irp-cdn.multiscreensite.com/2a06d0a3/dms3rep/multi/web.png"
                                    />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="320" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 7px; background-color: #0b9cab;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

[image: iOS Mail Dark Mode]

Comment: So, you are sending from your iPhone, using Apple Mail? I'm not sure if you are able to insert it, given it's just a signature, but you can try adding a `<style>` block with the `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` details, if you haven't already? Let me know if you need a proper answer. e.g. https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/

Comment: I think setting widths as 100% is what breaks the dark mode thing.